# alguien puede sabe porque en mis clases, aparece una "llave inglesa"

Tags: java

[image: Aparecen una llaves inglesas en mis clases & no me deja compilar el programa, es urgente se los agradeceria mucho]

Aparecen unas llaves inglesas arriba de mis clases & no me deja compilar nada del programa, es urgente & les agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: Podrías agregar más información sobre el IDE que estás utilizando, así otros usuarios pueden ayudarte. No olvides que cualquier detalle puede ser de utilidad.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta todas las veces que haga falta, usando el enlace Editar que esta justo bajo la pregunta. Añade detalles sobre tu proyecto, el IDE, etc.

Answer (score 1):

El IDE que usas es **NetBeans**, cuando aparece la llave encima de las clases significa que necesita ser compilado.

Dale sobre el botón derecho del raton a las clases donde te ponga la llave y le das a **Compile File.**

Un saludo!